# Hibernate - Accept Duplicates in Query

Tags: hibernate

I have a hibernate query that can and does return duplicate rows from legacy data.  Is there a way I can tell hibernate to accept the duplicate rows without having to create some sort of pseudo-key?

This is what my hbm looks like:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="mycompany.cms.domain">

    <class name="mycompany.cms.domain.DelDeadline" table="cms.del_deadlines">
        <id column="nid"                     name="nid"/>
        <property column="deadline_type"     name="deadline_type"/>
        <property column="del_run_date"      name="del_run_date"/>
        <property column="deadline_day"      name="deadline_day"/>
        <property column="deadline_time"     name="deadline_time"/>
    </class>

    <query name="DelDeadline.getAll">
            <![CDATA[from mycompany.cms.domain.DelDeadline]]>
    </query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: No. Hibernate needs a unique and immutable ID for every entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as JB Nizet said Hibernate needs a unique id. you could map all columns as one big compositeId, then you would get distinct results but the nid could be duplicated